# ¿Cómo actualizar Filtros en R Shiny para luego renderizar un gráfico que se alimente de una base de datos filtrada?

Tags: rstudio, shiny

Tengo el siguiente UI(incluiré un fragmento):

```
ui <-navbarPage("Comparativo elementos",
    tabPanel('elemento 1',
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(h4("Texto"),
                            selectInput(inputId = "Input11",label="Input 1",choices = datos$Input),
                            selectInput(inputId = "Input12",label="Input 2",choices = NULL),
                            selectInput(inputId = "Input13",label = "Input 3",choices = NULL),
               mainPanel(h3("Gráfico elemento 1"),
                         plotOutput("grafico11"))
               ))
             )))
```

Y para utilizar el Plot utilizo en el server lo siguiente:

```
server <- function(session,input,output){

 #------------------------------GRÁFICO---------------------------------------------------
  output$grafico11<-renderPlot({
  #------------------------------PREPROCESAMIENTO-------------------------------------------
    observe({
      x1= datos %>% filter(Item1== input$Input11)
      updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "Input21",label = "Input 2",choices = x1$Item2)
      y1= datos %>% filter(Item1==input$Input21, Item2== input$Input21)
      updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "Input31",label = "Input 3",choices = y1$Item3)
    })
   #----------------------------CREACIÓN GRÁFICO--------------------------------
      compare= datos %>% filter(Item1==input$Input11 & 
                                   Item2==input$Input12 & 
                                   Item3==input$Input13) %>% 
        select(Var1,Var2,Var3) %>% 
        column_to_rownames(.,var="Var1") %>% select(Var2,Var3)
      names(compare) = c("Var2","Var3")
      compare= rbind(rep(15,2),rep(1,2),compare)
      # Color vector
      colors_border=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.9) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.9))
      colors_in=c( rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.4), rgb(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.4) , rgb(0.7,0.5,0.1,0.4) )
      # plot with default options:
      radarchart(compare  , axistype=1 , 
               #custom polygon
               pcol=colors_border , pfcol=colors_in , plwd=4 , plty=1,
               #custom the grid
               cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
               #custom labels
               vlcex=0.8)
      # Add a legend
      legend("topleft", legend = rownames(compare[-c(1,2),]), bty = "n", 
           pch=20 , col=colors_in , text.col = "grey", cex=1.2, pt.cex=3)
  })

}
```

Esto me muestra el gráfico de radar y tampoco tengo problemas en la UI, el problema es que no obedece a los filtros y está mostrando el primer elemento filtrado en cada item, cuando trato de elegir otros elementos en la navegación de elementos de los filtros, vuelve a los que estaban.